# Why is format changing when file is converting to PDF?

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I want to convert the HTML page to pdf for this I have used flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 .added flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 and flying-saucer-core dependencies but when a pdf file is generated its format changes some CSS is not applying to PDF file.
my code like this:

```
        String xHtml = convertToXhtml(htmlContent);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml);
        renderer.setScaleToFit(true);
        renderer.layout();
        final File pdfFile = new File("fileName.pdf");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
```

to convert Html to XHTML i write this code:

```
            Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
            tidy.setInputEncoding(UTF-8);
            tidy.setOutputEncoding(UTF-8);
            tidy.setXHTML(true);
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new 
            ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes(UTF-8));
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
           <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
           <version>9.1.6</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
           <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
           <version>9.1.6</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific: Please [provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that show what you are doing and demonstrates the kinds of CSS that are not applied. Generally speaking I wouldn't expect `iText` to be able to perfectly represent all CSS.

Comment: Make sense to add the flying-saucer tag, right? Can you also supply your PDF (or some example) which illustrates the behavior?